# Linq2Xml - Getting parent items based on their children's attribute value

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a simple xml:

```
<forms for="ApplicationTestSettings">
    <form name="Parameter12Settings" title="Parameter12 Settings" url="/Parameter12Settings">
        <roles>
            <role name="Parameter12-Reader" />
            <role name="Parameter12-Writer" can-add="1" can-edit="1" can-delete="0" />
        </roles>
    </form>
    <form name="Parameter34Settings" title="Parameter 34 Settings" url="/Parameter34Settings">
        <roles>
            <role name="Parameter34-Reader" />
            <role name="Parameter34-Writer" can-add="1" can-edit="1" can-delete="0" />
        </roles>
    </form>
</forms>
```

I need a form collection based on role element's attribute value. I have a list:

```
List<string> roles = new List<string>();
roles.Add("Parameter12-Reader");
roles.Add("Parameter34-Writer");
```

I try to get items with using this query:

```
var forms = root.Descendants("form")
                .Where(form => roles.Contains(form.Element("roles")
                                                  .Element("role")
                                                  .Attribute("name").Value)).ToList();
```

Unfortunately this query analyzes only the first role in all form/roles blocks. Can anybody tell me, how do I have to define this query for getting all form element, where roles list contains the xml role names?

Thanks,
D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var forms = root.Descendants("form")
                .Where(form => form.Elements("roles")
                                   .Elements("role")
                                   .Attributes("name")
                                   .Any(n => roles.Contains(n.Value))
                       ).ToList();
```